# Spring cannot roll back committed transactions when one datasource transaction failed

Tags: java, database, spring, transactions

I am working on one microservice, which involves multiple datasources. For the sake of simplify, I am using two datasources here, MySql and Oracle. This is the pseudo code.

```
    domain.withNewTransaction {
      mySql.executeUpdate("update mySqlTable")
      oracle.executeUpdate("update oracleTable")
    }
```

One day there was an exception thrown up when trying to commit oracle update, however, I found mysql update is successfully committed and not rolled back. 
I found the framework is using **ChainedTransactionManager.java** to manage multiple datasources commit. This is the code for commit method.

```
public void commit(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {

        MultiTransactionStatus multiTransactionStatus = (MultiTransactionStatus) status;

        boolean commit = true;
        Exception commitException = null;
        PlatformTransactionManager commitExceptionTransactionManager = null;

        for (PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager : reverse(transactionManagers)) {

            if (commit) {

                try {
                    multiTransactionStatus.commit(transactionManager);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    commit = false;
                    commitException = ex;
                    commitExceptionTransactionManager = transactionManager;
                }

            } else {

                // after unsucessfull commit we must try to rollback remaining transaction managers

                try {
                    multiTransactionStatus.rollback(transactionManager);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOGGER.warn("Rollback exception (after commit) (" + transactionManager + ") " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
            }
        }

        if (multiTransactionStatus.isNewSynchonization()) {
            synchronizationManager.clearSynchronization();
        }

        if (commitException != null) {
            boolean firstTransactionManagerFailed = commitExceptionTransactionManager == getLastTransactionManager();
            int transactionState = firstTransactionManagerFailed ? HeuristicCompletionException.STATE_ROLLED_BACK
                    : HeuristicCompletionException.STATE_MIXED;
            throw new HeuristicCompletionException(transactionState, commitException);
        }
    }
```

It turns out when one datasource commit failed, ChainedTransactionManager will only roll back the remaining uncommitted ones, nothing to do with committed transactions.

I understand it's complicated and risky to roll back the committed transaction. I'd like to know for application developer if any better idea to handle this multiple datasources transaction commit failure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find some info from grails document http://docs.grails.org/3.1.4/guide/conf.html#configGORM

**Transactions across multiple datasources**

Grails uses the Best Efforts 1PC pattern for handling transactions across multiple datasources.

The Best Efforts 1PC pattern is fairly general but can fail in some circumstances that the developer must be aware of. This is a non-XA pattern that involves a synchronized single-phase commit of a number of resources. Because the 2PC is not used, it can never be as safe as an XA transaction, but is often good enough if the participants are aware of the compromises.

**The basic idea is to delay the commit of all resources as late as possible in a transaction so that the only thing that can go wrong is an infrastructure failure (not a business-processing error). Systems that rely on Best Efforts 1PC reason that infrastructure failures are rare enough that they can afford to take the risk in return for higher throughput. If business-processing services are also designed to be idempotent, then little can go wrong in practice.**

The BE1PC implementation was added in Grails 2.3.6. . Before this change additional datasources didn't take part in transactions initiated in Grails. The transactions in additional datasources were basically in auto commit mode. In some cases this might be the wanted behavior. One reason might be performance: on the start of each new transaction, the BE1PC transaction manager creates a new transaction to each datasource. It's possible to leave an additional datasource out of the BE1PC transaction manager by setting transactional = false in the respective configuration block of the additional dataSource. Datasources with readOnly = true will also be left out of the chained transaction manager (since 2.3.7).

By default, the BE1PC implementation will add all beans implementing the Spring PlatformTransactionManager interface to the chained BE1PC transaction manager. For example, a possible JMSTransactionManager bean in the Grails application context would be added to the Grails BE1PC transaction manager's chain of transaction managers.

You can exclude transaction manager beans from the BE1PC implementation with the this configuration option:

grails.transaction.chainedTransactionManagerPostProcessor.blacklistPattern = '.*'
The exclude matching is done on the name of the transaction manager bean. The transaction managers of datasources with transactional = false or readOnly = true will be skipped and using this configuration option is not required in that case.
XA and Two-phase Commit
When the Best Efforts 1PC pattern isn't suitable for handling transactions across multiple transactional resources (not only datasources), there are several options available for adding XA/2PC support to Grails applications.

The Spring transactions documentation contains information about integrating the JTA/XA transaction manager of different application servers. In this case, you can configure a bean with the name transactionManager manually in resources.groovy or resources.xml file.

There is also Atomikos plugin available for XA support in Grails applications.

Best Efforts 1PC pattern link: 
https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html?page=2